# Combo box property changed property not updating when selecting a different item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Some reason the "Unit" property is not being updated when I click on a different item in the combo box. Only way it updates is when you tab away. Clicking elsewhere doesn't work either. Changing the selection should definitely trigger an update...

```
                            x:Name="UnitConcue">
                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static 
                                                                                    ene:Sysleton.UnitValues}}"
                                                                                Text="{Binding Unit}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
                                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static 
                                                                                    ene:Sysleton.UnitValues}}"
                                                                                Text="{Binding Unit}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>            
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? people were able to provide an answer and it's pretty obvious what the issue is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your binding to

```
"{Binding Unit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Beat me by one minute XD